# Beamer: How to add hooks to \item in itemize/enumerate environments

Tags: beamer, lists

I'm trying to add hooks to `\item` in Beamer, but its internal gear is too complex for me.

I tried `etoobox`'s `\preto`, `\pretocmd` and the similar commands from `xpatch`. Also, `\AtBeginEnvironment` won't do the job. All of them **break the overlay system**.

Long story short, a simpler vision of my goal is to, for example, put all item in a framebox. So, I should use something like:

```
\xpretocmd{\item}{\framebox\bgroup}
\xapptocmd{\item}{\egroup}
```

This is a MWD:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Current behaviour:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item One
        \item <2>Two
        \item Three
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    Expected new behaviour result:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item \framebox{One}
        \item <2> \framebox{Two}
        \item \framebox{Three}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Please note that the `\framebox{}` is just an example. I'd intend to add a few more things there..., but first things first. :-)

Comment: Have a look at the `getitems` package, see e.g. https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2006 for an example

Comment: (no idea if it works with beamer, but that's one of the few ways I can think of to get the body of an item)

Comment: Can you add what your actual use case is? Maybe there are other ways, e.g. like the `grayenv` trick I used at https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `getitems` worked for me (thanks!). It does exactly what I wanted.

With the item body, I can check for Beamer overlays and bullet replacements and deal with them later.

This is a proof of concept.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{getitems}

\let\Item\item
\let\Itemize\itemize
\let\endItemize\enditemize

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_item_structure_seq
\cs_new:Npn \dc_do_item:n #1 {
    \regex_extract_once:nnNTF { \A<(.*?)>\s*\[(.*?)\](.*) } { #1 } \g_item_structure_seq {
        \mybox<\seq_item:Nn \g_item_structure_seq { 2 }>
        [\seq_item:Nn \g_item_structure_seq { 3 }]
        {\seq_item:Nn \g_item_structure_seq { 4 }}
    } {
        \regex_extract_once:nnNTF { \A\[(.*?)\]\s*<(.*?)>(.*) } { #1 } \g_item_structure_seq {
            \mybox<\seq_item:Nn \g_item_structure_seq { 3 }>
            [\seq_item:Nn \g_item_structure_seq { 2 }]
            {\seq_item:Nn \g_item_structure_seq { 4 }}
        } {
            \regex_extract_once:nnNTF { \A<(.*?)>(.*) } { #1 } \g_item_structure_seq {
                \mybox<\seq_item:Nn \g_item_structure_seq { 2 }>
                {\seq_item:Nn \g_item_structure_seq { 3 }}
            } {
                \regex_extract_once:nnNTF { \A\[(.*?)\](.*) } { #1 } \g_item_structure_seq {
                    \mybox
                    [\seq_item:Nn \g_item_structure_seq { 2 }]
                    {\seq_item:Nn \g_item_structure_seq { 3 }}
                } {
                    \mybox{#1}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    \vspace{1em}\par
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \doitem } { m } {
    \dc_do_item:n { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\RenewEnviron{itemize}{%
    \expandafter\gatheritems\expandafter{\BODY}%
    \begin{Itemize}
        \loopthroughitemswithcommand{\doitem}%
    \end{Itemize}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mybox}{D<>{1-}om}{%
    \visible<#1>{%
        \IfValueTF{#2}{
            \Item[#2]\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}#3\end{minipage}}%
        }{
            \Item\framebox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}#3\end{minipage}}%
        }
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    MyList:\bigskip

    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is Baskara: $x = \frac{b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$
        \item <+-> This is an array: \texttt{int a[10];}
        \item [$\diamond$] Use angle brackets\ldots ${<}a{>}$
        \item <2-3>[$\equiv$] Simple text
        \item [*]<2-3> Nested \texttt{enumerate}:
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item One
            \item Two
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And yes! I can do a better regex matching :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could define a custom macro which you can use instead of `\item`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\newcommand<>{\myitem}[1]{\item#2 \framebox{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Current behaviour:

    \begin{itemize}
        \myitem{One}
        \myitem<2>{Two}
        \myitem{Three}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really ok. I wanted to not having to add braces to `\items`.